# PHP Fatal error: Class 'App\Providers\ServiceProvider' not found, after I fixed err Laravel migration: unique key is too long,

Tags: php

I just started to learn Laravel 5.4 and trying to migrate a users table in Laravel. When I run my migration I get this error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

After following [this tutorial](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error), I now have another error:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'App\Providers\ServiceProvider' not found

My migration code is

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    //
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a new service provider and put the above code in that, or did you put the above code in the `AppServiceProvider` class? Either way, can you please post the entire code for the file and identify it, that may help us help you resolve the issue.

Comment: my code is in AppServiceProvider class and my entire code is...,,,<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    
   public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}

    public function register()
    {
   
    }
}

Comment: Does your `AppServiceProvider` class still have the `use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;` statement in it?

Comment: No, i changed that to this code "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;"

Comment: Don't replace any thing just add new thing that is in article. So keep as previouse code also.

Comment: I encountered this issue when my `namespace` deceleration for `AppServiceProvider` came after my `use` statement for `ServiceProvider` in the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the `use` statement that identifies where the `ServiceProvider` class is. Since the `AppServiceProvider` class extends `ServiceProvider`, but there is no `use` statement, PHP assumes that the class can be found in the same namespace as `AppServiceProvider`. This is why it can't find `\App\Providers\ServiceProvider` - because `\App\Providers` is the namespace of the `AppServiceProvider` class.

Try this

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: thanks alot @stratedge , it's working only by adding 'use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;' with my code, what i did wrong  is changing instead of adding 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;' once again I thanking you to solve the issue.